# *ngFor trackby returns a constant, always the same, what errors could it produce?

Tags: angular

Say you have *ngFor, looping through array of objects. What if you add trackby function, returning constant, what issues can this produce, if you maybe replace arrayOfObjects with arrayOfObjects2? I see same behavior, if trackby returns null, index, 1

```
// test.component.ts
public arrayOfObjects = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
public arrayOfObjects2 = [{a: 5, b: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8}]
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => this.arrayOfObjects = this.arrayOfObjects2, 2000);
}
iReturnConstant(index, item) {return 1;}

// test.component.html
<tr *ngFor="let entry of arrayOfObjects; trackBy: iReturnConstant">
<th>{{ entry.a }}</th>
  <td>{{ entry.b }}</td>
</tr>
```